# Get attribute of element clicked

Tags: ember.js

I have following in my template

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" tab-name="Personal Information" {{action "switchTab" target="view"}}>Personal Information</a>
```

And my view is as follow

```
App.SidebarView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'sidebar',
    actions: {
        switchTab: function(e){
             //Some Code
        }
    }
});
```

how can get the tab-name attribute upon click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to capture a DOM related event like `click` to get the event object, inside an `action` no event object is passed along, so try to change your view to this:

In your Template remove the `action`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" tab-name="Personal Information">Personal Information</a>
```

Then in your View register for the `click` event:

```
App.SidebarView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'sidebar',
  click: function(e){
    var tabName = $(e.target).attr("tab-name");
    console.log(tabName);
  }
});
```

Example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ETUroGA/1/edit

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it so:

```
App.SidebarView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'sidebar',
    actions: {
        switchTab: function(event, view){
            var tab-name = $(event.target).attr("tab-name")
            // some code
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried that earlier but it seems that event is undefined

Comment: The method defined in `actions` does not have access to `event`.